# Angular 7 Phone number validators pattern

Tags: regex, angular, angular-forms

I want to validate phone number in angular form
Need to allow:- Brackets ( ) and spaces for phone numbers – e.g (+64) 123 4567 or 0800 660 660
I wand to find best regex for validate this.

`telephone: ['', Validators.compose([Validators.required,Validators.minLength(7),Validators.maxLength(17),                                          Validators.pattern('(^((\\+64-?)|0)?[0-9]{10}$)')])]`

Comment: What are all the types of phone numbers you want to accept?  You should this information in your question.

Comment: All New Zealand phone numbers    
 With or without +64 e.g (+64) , +64        
 Need to allow spaces to type like this 0800 660 660       
 Min length 7       
 Max length 17

Comment: Great, now just include those rules as sample data in your question and someone would be happy to help you.